# How to make a generic type to always be a generic typed List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, blazor

I have a class that inherits from another class

```
public abstract class BaseMultiSelect<TValue, Item> : BaseSelect<TValue, Item>        
{
    //...
}
```

But inside `BaseMultiSelect` I want that `TValue` should always be a `List<T>`, so the `TValue` on `BaseSelect` will always be a `List`.

How can I do that? I tried adding type constraints, but no sucess. Is this even possible?

Comment: _"so the TValue on BaseSelect will always be a List"_ Do you mean to always use `List`, or are you allowing anything that derives from `List`? That makes the difference between using generics in your derived class or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `TValue` should always be the same type, don't pass it to `BaseMultiSelect` as a type parameter. You can still specify it for `BaseSelect` without specifying it in the type parameters for `BaseMultiSelect`.

```
public abstract class BaseMultiSelect<T, Item> : BaseSelect<List<T>, Item>        
{
    //...
}
```

or

```
public abstract class BaseMultiSelect<Item> : BaseSelect<List<Item>, Item>        
{
    //...
}
```